# Make a custom field required when certain condition is fulfilled

Tags: custom-field, picklist, validation-rule, required-field

Could you please advise and give me an example of a validation rule to help me make a custom field required when a picklist value is selected.

I have a picklist called Type and a custom field called Description.

The Description field should become required only if the picklist value “Other” is selected.

Could you please advise and give me an example of how such restriction can be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

While it's not possible to control field visibility on a standard page layout. You can have a validation rule (VR) to display a message, notifying them that the value is required:

```
OR(
  AND(
   ISPICKVAL(Type__c, 'Other'),
   ISBLANK(Description__c)
  ),
  AND(
   NOT(ISPICKVAL(Type__c, 'Other')),
   NOT(ISBLANK(Description__c))
  )
)
```

And have a message like ***"Description is required when (and ONLY) Type is 'Other'"***, or you can split this formula into 2 separate VRs (using just `AND` from each condition) if you want to have a custom notification for each case - e.g. asking users to erase `Description` value if `Type` is not `Other`

Comment: This could be written shorter as `ISPICKVAL(...) = ISBLANK(...)`. This way it will err if both are true or both are false.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to achieve this.

1.If you have to set up a validation rule like.

AND( ISPICKVAL(picklist_field, text_literal) ,ISBLANK(Custom field))

Like

AND(ISPICKVAL(stagename,"Closed Lost"),ISBLANK(Additional_Comments_reasonlost__c))

It's out of box functionality.

2.If you need to highlight the custom filed only in a specific criteria.You have to go for visualforce pages.Like above Russel baker 1 said.You have to create a visualforce page and can include with in a layout.@Dylan D

Answer (score -1):

Create a validation rule something like

```
AND((!ISPICKVAL(Type,'Other')) , !Null(Description))
```

This validation rule will thrown the error if the field (Type != other) and (descrption is != null).

Comment: I received an
Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Answer (score -1):

Fields highlight on Condition can not be achievable through standard functions. You have to wright VF pages. 
Action region and action support function and rendered.

Answer (score -1):

1. On Standard UI conditional visibility of fields is not possible. For this you can do changes on trigger and throw an error message when type is not `Other` selected and there is value in `description` field.
2. Create a VF page and control the rendering of input field using rerender attribute.

Hope it helps you :)